# Which Python library should I use to generate Custom Charts?

Tags: visualization

I'm currently using ChartExpo to create custom charts like [Multi Axis Line Chart](https://chartexpo.com/charts/multi-axis-line-chart) for comparison. Could you suggest some Python libraries for to accomplish this in Python?

Answer (score 1):

The standard Python visualization library is [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/), and it supports the kind of multi-axis charts that you linked to, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5484922/674487), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27965928/674487) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45925049/674487).

You may also use [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/), which builds on top of matplotlib and usually you get more visually appealing results, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67325343/674487).

Finally, you can also use [Plotly](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py), e.g. [this](https://plotly.com/python/multiple-axes/).